# newtxmath in BasicTeX: Not working out of the box

Tags: symbols, newtxmath, font-metrics

I have a fresh installation of BasicTeX and cannot get `newtxmath` to work. There seem to be problems with math glyphs.

Running this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
$+$
\end{document}
```

results in these error messages:

```
Font \csname\endcsname=zxxrl7z at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \end{document}
Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <5.5> not available(Font) size <5> substituted
Size substitutions with differences(Font) up to 0.5pt have occurred.
```

But I just cannot find out how to fix this, e.g. which extra files to install...

The full log file reads:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.9.27)  9 OCT     2017 18:49
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Sandbox.tex
(./Sandbox.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 22 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/newtxmath.sty
Package: newtxmath 2017/09/11 v1.527

`newtxmath' v1.527, 2017/09/11 Math macros based on txfonts (msharpe)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2017/09/02 v2.17a AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks14
\ex@=\dimen103
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen104
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count87
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 213.
\uproot@=\count88
\leftroot@=\count89
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 375.
\classnum@=\count90
\DOTSCASE@=\count91
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 472.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 475.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 596.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen105
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 712.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 713.
\macc@depth=\count92
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count93
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count94
\dspbrk@lvl=\count95
\tag@help=\toks15
\row@=\count96
\column@=\count97
\maxfields@=\count98
\andhelp@=\toks16
\eqnshift@=\dimen106
\alignsep@=\dimen107
\tagshift@=\dimen108
\tagwidth@=\dimen109
\totwidth@=\dimen110
\lineht@=\dimen111
\@envbody=\toks17
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks18
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2817.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2818.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks19
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks20

(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count99
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kastrup/binhex.tex)
\tx@Isdigit=\count100
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 155.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 155.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 155.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/b/n on input line 156.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathsf on input line 162.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/cmss/m/n on input line 162.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/cmss/m/n on input line 162.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathit on input line 163.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/cmr/m/it on input line 163.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/cmr/m/it on input line 163.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathtt on input line 164.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/cmtt/m/n on input line 164.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/cmtt/m/n on input line 164.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 166.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/cmr/b/n on input line 166.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/cmr/b/n on input line 166.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/cmr/b/it on input line 167.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/cmss/b/n on input line 168.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/cmtt/b/n on input line 169.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `letters' on input line 220.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/ntxmi/m/it on input line 220.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/ntxmi/m/it on input line 220.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/ntxmi/m/it --> OML/ntxmi/b/it on input line 221.
\symlettersA=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `lettersA' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/ntxmia/m/it --> U/ntxmia/b/it on input line 237.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `symbols' on input line 258.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMS' has changed to `LMS' for symbol font
(Font)              `symbols' in the math version `normal' on input line 258.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> LMS/ntxsy/m/n on input line 258.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMS' has changed to `LMS' for symbol font
(Font)              `symbols' in the math version `bold' on input line 258.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> LMS/ntxsy/m/n on input line 258.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  LMS/ntxsy/m/n --> LMS/ntxsy/b/n on input line 259.
\symAMSm=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `AMSm' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/ntxsym/m/n --> U/ntxsym/b/n on input line 282.
\symsymbolsC=\mathgroup6
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbolsC' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/ntxsyc/m/n --> U/ntxsyc/b/n on input line 303.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `largesymbols' on input line 316.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `LMX' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `normal' on input line 3
16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> LMX/ntxexx/m/n on input line 316.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `LMX' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `bold' on input line 316
.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> LMX/ntxexx/m/n on input line 316.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  LMX/ntxexx/m/n --> LMX/ntxexx/b/n on input line 317.
\symlargesymbolsTXA=\mathgroup7
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbolsTXA' in version `bold'

(Font)                  U/ntxexa/m/n --> U/ntxexa/b/n on input line 331.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \lgroup on input line 502.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rgroup on input line 503.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \lmoustache on input line 504.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rmoustache on input line 505.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \lfloor on input line 511.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rfloor on input line 512.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \lceil on input line 513.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rceil on input line 514.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \lbrace on input line 515.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rbrace on input line 516.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \langle on input line 517.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rangle on input line 519.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mid on input line 521.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \arrowvert on input line 523.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \vert on input line 524.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \parallel on input line 525.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \Arrowvert on input line 526.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \Vert on input line 527.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \updownarrow on input line 529.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \Updownarrow on input line 530.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \lvert on input line 535.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rvert on input line 536.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \lVert on input line 537.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math delimiter \rVert on input line 538.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \not on input line 2102.
)
(./Sandbox.aux)
\openout1 = `Sandbox.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/ntxmi/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OML+ntxmi on input line 6.


(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/omlntxmi.fd
File: omlntxmi.fd 2015/08/25 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OML/ntxmi.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/ntxexa/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+ntxexa on input line 6.

(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/untxexa.fd
File: untxexa.fd 2012/04/16 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxexa.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LMS/ntxsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for LMS+ntxsy on input line 6.


(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/lmsntxsy.fd
File: lmsntxsy.fd 2016/07/02 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for LMS/ntxsy.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LMX/ntxexx/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for LMX+ntxexx on input line 6
.

(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/lmxntxexx.fd
File: lmxntxexx.fd 2016/07/03 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for LMX/ntxexx.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <5.5> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 10.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+ntxmia on input line 10.

(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/untxmia.fd
File: untxmia.fd 2016/01/31 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxmia.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+ntxsym on input line 10.


(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/untxsym.fd
File: untxsym.fd 2015/03/20 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxsym.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+ntxsyc on input line 10.


(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/untxsyc.fd
File: untxsyc.fd 2012/04/12 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for U/ntxsyc.
) [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
! Font \csname\endcsname=zxxrl7z at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not 
found.
<to be read again> 
                   \endgroup \set@typeset@protect 
l.12     \end{document}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

] (./Sandbox.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 0.5pt have occurred.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2211 strings out of 494437
 25513 string characters out of 6166645
 69633 words of memory out of 5000000
 5553 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 16403 words of font info for 45 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 319 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 34i,4n,22p,245b,111s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10
.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/txfonts/rtxr.p
fb>
Output written on Sandbox.pdf (1 page, 12876 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 16 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Install `boondox` with TeX Live Utility. But I repeat my suggestion from another comment: why not simply install the full MacTeX and forget about missing packages?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works seamlessly. Well, I wanted to try a minimalistic approach. It also saves precious SSD space...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for files in TeX Live through the `tlmgr` command line utility.

On a terminal window issue

```
tlmgr info zxxrl7z
```

I get the following output

```
tlmgr: cannot find package zxxrl7z, searching for other matches:

Packages containing `zxxrl7z' in their title/description:

Packages containing files matching `zxxrl7z':
boondox:
    texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/boondox/zxxrl7z.tfm
```

According to the documentation, if the search fails on the installed packages, it is also performed on the global list in the remote repository. From this you easily deduce that you need to install `boondox`, which you can do either with `tlmgr` (normally needing `sudo`) or TeX Live Utility.